# nullpointerexcetion at findviewbyid

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview

i'm trying to build a simple app that downloads a png file from my pc decodes it and sets it in an imageview in a new activity that start after a button press.

everything that has to do with the networking, and decoding of the file seems to work properly, but i seem to be getting a lot of errors when using "findviewbyid", (android studio) it suggests the correct id but when i run it, exceptions are thrown and the app crashes.

(When creating a new activity in android studio it creates a placeholder fragment. Should I write the code in the OncreateView of the fragment?)

activity xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.show"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app.show$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fromaster"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code (onCreate):

```
public class show extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
    ImageView v;
    v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fromaster);
    byte[] raw;

    if (v == null){Log.d("at view","empty");}

    raw = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("pic");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(raw,0,raw.length);
    if (bitmap == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"empty      bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        try{
            v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);}
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("at setting bitmap","error",e);
        }
    }


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
02-02 10:48:34.330  21950-21950/com.example.app E/FragmentManager﹕ No view found for id 0x7f080000 (com.example.app:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41bd5c38 #0 id=0x7f080000}
```

EDIT: i have used the OncreateView of the fragment, still an exception when using findviewbyid:

java code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false);

        ImageView v = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fromaster);
        byte[] raw;

        if (v == null){Log.d("at view","empty");}

        raw = getArguments().getByteArray("pic");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(raw,0,raw.length);
        if (bitmap == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"empty bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            try{
                v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);}
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("at setting bitmap","error",e);
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

logcat error:

```
02-02 11:29:24.335  25479-25479/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 25479
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.show}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.app.show$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(show.java:69)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
```

Comment: Is "fromaster" inside "activity_show"? We dont see activity_show.xml. Put some more log, please.

Comment: Your problem is @ `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();`. Now you need to post the proper `activity_show.xml` and  the fragment code for the 1st stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activity_show.xml` does not have `ImageView`

ImageView is in `fragment.xml`. `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout. So if you `findViewById` returns null then you referenced the wrong id for the view or you do not have the view in the xml that you inflate.

My guess is your activity has a framelayout which is a container to which you add or replace framents. The initialization of `ImageView` should go to `onCreateView` of Fragment and im your `show` activity you need to add the fragment to `FrameLayout`.

Edit:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false);
ImageView v = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fromaster);
```

Comment: inside the OncreateView of the placeholder fragment 'findviewbyid' isnt even recognized.

Comment: @TalKopel post the code pls. it will work if you do it right. And pls read the docs it has examples of what you are doing

Comment: @TalKopel for the rest you can read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. pls read the docs once before you go ahead